# Angular 6 Change detection - how to setup the child component?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

My parent angular component has a nested child component. That child component is a list of buttons. When one button is clicked a value is passed to the child component. That child component is then updated accordingly to an id. I have implemented some change detection to the child. When child register an update comming from the parent, it runs the ngOnChanges hook. Here i call my backend and data returns

My code is working fine, but it seems like a hack. As you can see in the following code, I detach the changeDetection object. In the ngOnChanges - in the subscribe section I reattach the cd again. I dont like

Can you guys give me some pointers on this?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-challenge',
  templateUrl: './challenge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./challenge.component.css']
})
export class ChallengeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() focusedChallenge: string;

  eventId = {};
  challenge: Challenge;
  userSelection;

  constructor(
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private eventService: EventService,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {  
this.cd.detach()
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventId = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.id;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.eventService.getChallenge(this.focusedChallenge)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.cd.reattach();
          console.log(res)
          this.challenge = res
        },
        err => { console.log(err) }
      )
      challengeSelected.currentValue.toUpperCase();
  }
```

**Update in response to answer**

It does actually give me the result that I want with ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges). But it gives we an error still. Saying that it is undefined.

[image]

The options array is a nested array on Challenge

The object returned from db

```
{_id: "5b86dc5bfb6fc03893e55001", shortEventId: "d2d3", organization: "Brædstrup", name: "1. december", winner: "", …}
born: "1. decemberplus andet"
endDate: "2018-10-06T23:59:00.000Z"
id: "5b86dc5bfb6fc03893e55001"
name: "1. december"
options: Array(4)
0: {name: "Matas", isCorrect: true, description: "Matas er den førende skib", image: "https://cityxpstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/Matas.png", id: null}
1: {name: "Føtex", isCorrect: false, description: "Føtex er en dejlig butik", image: "https://cityxpstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/Føtex.png", id: null, …}
2: {name: "Kvickly", isCorrect: false, description: "Kvickly er en dejlig butik", image: "https://cityxpstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/Matas.png", id: null, …}
3: {name: "MC Jørgensen", isCorrect: false, description: "MC Jørgensen er en dejlig butik", image: "https://cityxpstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/Matas.png", id: null}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
organization: "Brædstrup"
shortEventId: "d2d3"
startDate: "2018-10-06T00:00:00.000Z"
winner: ""
_id: "5b86dc5bfb6fc03893e55001"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything with the `ChangeDetectorRef`. Any time that `focusedChallenge` is changed, it should fire `ngOnChanges`

Comment: The problem is that my view is updated first - but is has no values to attach. It gives me a [object] is undefined error. So it seems that I need to detach the view first in order to suppres  errors.

Comment: You can just handle the case of it being undefined, by performing an `if` check on it. You can use something like `if (suchAndSuch != null)`, or if it's in the template, you can use `suchAndSuch?.myProp`, where the `?` will prevent it from trying to read `myProp` is `suchAndSuch` is null or undefined

Comment: Could you give me an example? Where should I make the check?

Comment: Which is the variable is undefined? Can you post the actual error message please?

Comment: I have updated with the object .. How do I copy the error text best?

Comment: The error in within `ChallengeComponent.html`, can you please post that file?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ChallengeComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10458)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10662)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10459)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)

Comment: Yep, can you post the ChallengeComponent.html file so that I can provide a valid example please?

Comment: <mat-radio-group *ngFor="let option of challenge.options; let idx = index">
  <br>
  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" value="{{option.name}}" [(ngModel)]="option.name" name="radio" hidden (change)="postAnswer(option)" [checked]="idx === 0">
    <div class="dashed" [ngClass]="{'green': option.selected == true}">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="{{option.image}}" alt="{{option.name}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>{{option.description}}</p>
  </label>
  <br>

</mat-radio-group>

Comment: So change it to `let option of challenge?.options`

Comment: Yes, thanks. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using string type input, you don't need to capture any ChangeDetection. So better you remove the `ChangeDetectorRef` and let the angular fire the `ngOnChanges` method whenever the `@Input` value is getting changed.

Your code should be as -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-challenge',
  templateUrl: './challenge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./challenge.component.css']
})
export class ChallengeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() focusedChallenge: string;

  eventId = {};
  challenge: Challenge;
  userSelection;

  constructor(
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private eventService: EventService,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {  
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventId = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.id;
  }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    let newFocusedChallenge  = changes["focusedChallenge"].currentValue;

    this.eventService.getChallenge(newFocusedChallenge)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res)
          this.challenge = res;
          //challengeSelected.currentValue.toUpperCase(); //not sure if is required
        },
        err => { console.log(err) }
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this syntax? `changes["focusedChallenge"];.currentValue`

Comment: It is `changes["focusedChallenge"].currentValue;`. Corrected in answer as well.